# how to serve static files and media files in c panel for django project?

Tags: path, static, cpanel, media, serving

In local django port my media and static files are running but in c panel my css, js, img and other files are not working how to serve this files when comes to  c panel hosting provider? only html is shown in web page and other css, js and other files are not working when deployed by python set up in c panel.